# How to linearly get data from NGRX store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am having a hard time using NGRX's data access patterns cleanly. So right now I am pulling data from my NGRX store like this:

```
logBooksAndAuthors() {
    const books$ = this.store.select(store => store.books);
    const authors$ = this.store.select(store => store.authors);

    books$.subscribe((books: Book[]) => {
       authors$.subscribe((authors: Authors[]) => {
            console.log(books);
            console.log(authors);
        });
    });
}
```

Depending on the business logic, getting data from the store this way can result in very deeply nested callbacks. Ideally, I would want to rewrite the subscriptions in a much more linear manner:

```
    const books$ = this.store.select(store => store.books);
    const authors$ = this.store.select(store => store.authors);

    const books = books$.subscribe((books: Book[]) => {
        return books;
    });

    const authors = $authors.subscribe((authors: Author[]) => {
        return authors;
    });

    console.log(books); // logs out a subscriber
    console.log(authors); // logs out a subscriber
}
```

I understand that my code above won't work because `books` and `authors` are assigned to subscribers in this case, but I wanted to point out how I'd ideally write the code. Thank you in advance and please let me know if I can clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `this.store.select` will return a stream. Since we have two streams here, to make them linear, we should combine them. RxJS has many combination operators.

Here is example using `combineLatest`

```
logBooksAndAuthors() {
  combineLatest([
    this.store.select(store => store.books),
    this.store.select(store => store.authors)
  ]).subscribe(([books, authors]) => {
    console.log(books, authors)
  })  
}
```

Check the other combination operator to suit your case here
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination

Comment: thanks @deerawan ! just follow up on this, if i wanted to get books data from my store and do a BUNCH of things to it, is the only way to do my logic in a callback? it just feels weird to me to write the bulk of my logic inside of a subscription callback: 


    ```const books$ = this.store.select(store => store.books);

    books$.subscribe((books: Book[]) => {
        // implement logic with books
    });

```

I would much rather do something like:

```const books = <some_ngrx_opereator> books$.subscribe((books: Book[]) => {
        return books;
    });

// do stuff
```

Comment: Hi @JohnGrayson you could modify the books using `pipe` in `this.store.select`. For example using `map` operator: `this.store.select(store => store.books).pipe(map(... => ...))`